# Does "left over from" make sense?

Tags: grammar

Is the usage of **from** in the below paragraph correct? I just now read it in the paper.

> In response to a question on the Kashmir issue, Mr. Lu said China’s position remained “clear and consistent”. “This is an issue that is **left over from** between India and Pakistan. We hope that the two sides will engage in friendly dialogue consultation and solve this issue and other related issues”.

Comment: No: you have two prepositions, *from* and *between*. *From* needs to be followed by what it is left over from (eg: "an issue that is left over from **the border dispute between India and Pakistan**").

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment:  No: you have two prepositions, *from* and *between*. *From* needs to be followed by what it is left over from (eg: "an issue that is left over from **the border dispute between India and Pakistan**").

That said, this sort of extemporaneous verbal response to a question is hardly unusual and I wouldn't consider it evidence of the speaker's unfamiliarity with English.  A more-generous reporter might have written it up as:  "This is an issue that is left over from -- between -- India and Pakistan."  But I wouldn't generally flag it as something that needed further clarification.

Comment: Hi Roger FYI.. link for news : https://www.thehindu.com/news/international/masood-azhars-designation-should-be-based-on-trilateral-consensus-china/article26532388.ece